# Android Draw inside a Webview

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, webview

I have a `webview` that I load facebook URL inside it.
I want to `draw` a button on each feed (Image/Video) inside the `webview` content. and on click, I want to capture the image/video link

similar to the image below
you can see in this image w red download button that is present on each feed media item

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it in two ways.

1. You'll have to insert your [button(element)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp) and manage its functionality using `Javascript` and to position your button, you can use [CSS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String))
2. You can place a static button on your layout and use *Intersection Observer API* via `Javascript` to get the reference of items which are visible on the screen.

To get data using `Javascript`, you will have to add a [JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) in your app.

Comment: hello, thank you for your response. Please note this button is visible on every feed while scrolling. this is not just one fixed button. can you please have a link where I can learn how to do that ?

Comment: Hi there, I have added relevant hyperlinks, it will get you started with.